# iOS Stackview inside ScrollView with preserve image aspect ratio

Tags: ios, autolayout, scrollview, stackview

I'm having a problem with scrollable content. Basically, I want to place one `ImageView` and one `Label` on the screen with `ImageView` width equals `screen` width. `height` depends on `intrinsic` `content` `aspect` `ratio` (while width is always equal screen width).

The `label` is 20 spacing bellow `ImageView`. That means whole content height may less or equal or even longer than the root `view`. What I have tried is to put `Label` and `ImageView` inside a `StackView` (`ImageView` has `Aspectfit` setting), Then put `StackView` inside `ScrollView`. Set up `constraints` as below.

[image]

The problem is the distance between ImageView and top `Superview` and between `ImageView` and `Label` is too big (ideally should be 20). Is there any way to achieve the desired outcome?

PS: I have tried to set stackView distributtion but no help

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can not understand the problem actually in storyboard screen shot. Can you show output of this ??

Comment: hi i have added output. Correct behavior should be imageview pin top left and right to the screen. label is bellow imageview 20

Comment: I think it's because of the image aspect ratio. Try once, set ImageView content mode = Scale to Fill

Comment: Hi but the purpose of the setup is to maintain the aspect ratio of the original image (scale height according to width)

Comment: Yes, that is fine and i understand what you want to implement. But just have a look with that try because you will get to know that how you have to create your image in width and height. One thing i can tell you that if you maintain aspect ratio of image your width and height both needs to change according to device.

Comment: yes both width and height need to change but I think we can set height depends on width (width is equal to screen width) and original aspect ratio

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181889/discussion-between-ios-wolf-and-le-khanh-vinh).

Comment: Set a background color on your image view and you'll see what's happening. Aspect-Fit changes the way the image is displayed *inside the image view* ... it doesn't change the ***frame*** of the image view. To do that, you'll need to add some code that gets the image size and calculates the Aspect-Fit rectangle, then change the frame of the image view.

Comment: Thanks. I'm also think so. I'm finding a function to resize imageView with parameter are its width and original intrinsic aspect ratio

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** Remove the aspect ratio constraint and add a height constraint for the `UIImageView`.

It’s important to understand that `UIImageView` is basically a container that holds an image, and its dimensions don’t necessarily reflect the image’s dimensions (unless you manually make them equal). When you selected Aspect Fit as `UIImageView`’s Content Mode, the size of the container didn’t change to correspond the image’s size; this setting only changed the way the image is placed inside the container.

As I can see in your screenshot, the `UIImageView`’s height is greater than its width; furthermore, the aspect ratio is fixed by the constraint you’ve added. When you placed a landscape-oriented image inside this container, the latter left white bars on the top and the bottom of the image (just like the black bars you see when you watch a widescreen video on an old monitor). Change Content Mode to Aspect Fill or Scale to Fill to see the actual size of the `UIImageView`.

To fix this, remove the aspect ratio constraint and set up a fixed height for either the `UIImageView` or the `UIStackView`. If I were you, I’d probably set the `UIStackView`’s height equal to `Safe Area` so that no matter how tall the stack view is, it doesn’t go beyond the screen boundaries.